# Bootstrap year calendar offset events

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I'm trying to display some reservations from the database into bootstrap year calendar but each reservation is offset with +1 month.

For example: 28 Nov, 2019 - 01 Dec, 2019 will be displayed like: 28 Dec, 2019 - 01 Jan, 2020

The only solution will be to add -1 month but in this case reservations from Dec-Jan will jump with one year and the 2020 will be unusable.

Did anyone meet this situation ?

```
.ready(function(){
                    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
                    jQuery('.calendar')
                    .calendar({
                                  style               : 'background',
                                  alwaysHalfDay       : true,
                                  enableContextMenu   : true,
                                  enableRangeSelection: true,
                                  dataSource: [

                                      <?php
                                      $bookings = $method->has_get_booking_of_room($room_id);
                                      foreach($bookings as $row) : //break;
                                      ?>
                                      {
                                          booking_id: '<?php echo $row["booking_id"];?>',
                                          startDate : new Date(<?php echo date("Y", $row['checkin_timestamp']);?>, <?php echo date("n",  $row['checkin_timestamp']);?>, <?php echo date("j", $row['checkin_timestamp']);?>),
                                          endDate   : new Date(<?php echo date("Y", $row['checkout_timestamp']);?>, <?php echo date("n", $row['checkout_timestamp']);?>, <?php echo date("j", $row['checkout_timestamp']);?>)
                                      },

                                      <?php
                                      endforeach;
                                      ?>
                                  ]

                              });

                });
```

Comment: You mean this product: https://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/? (You tagged fullCalendar, but that's something different.) Please confirm that, then show your code and full event data. It's unclear how you would expect us to help you without being able to see what you've written.

Comment: P.S. Since you provided no code or data, I will guess that maybe you defined your dates as JS Date objects, where the month numbers start at 0 instead of 1. Total guess, but that's all I can think of to create such a scenario.

Comment: Could you please share your code snippet.

Comment: I added the code. The year, month and day are correctly taken from database. The events shows up in calendar but are +1month offset.

Comment: and yes, is that product: bootstrap-year-calendar.com

Comment: I found here an explanation : [link]https://github.com/Paul-DS/bootstrap-year-calendar/issues/46 but I don't know how I should correct this